# Onboard does not work with touch

Tags: kernel, thinkpad, touchscreen, onboard

Onboard (the Ubuntu default onscreen keyboard) is working fine basically, but it does not work with touch. But this is what I need it for. I just can't press any button. I **can** press Onboard buttons with Mouse, Touchpad and my Wacom Pen, though. Touch is working fine in all other applications. I tried to fix it with the Onboard settings, but I couldn't find a solution. Maybe I have overlooked something?

I have a new Thinkpad Yoga 14. My OS is **Ubuntu 14.04 with the vivid kernel**. This was needed to support the hardware (especially pen and **touch**) correctly.

So what is causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Same problem here. Ubuntu 14.04 Lenovo ThinkPad x220 tablet.

Comment: I just updated to 16.04, which works pretty good for me. Maybe this is an option for you? It's also an LTS version.